# Probability of choosing a integer between 1-100 is in the interval $68<X\leq 85$

Tags: probability, statistics

I am coming out with 0.17 and I KNOW that there are 17 integers between 69 and 85 (counting 69) book says 0.16. Is the book wrong?

Comment: Yes, the book is wrong.

Comment: Heh. I hate it when that happens.

Comment: What book is that, you might want  to send an email so they can fix that

Comment: thanks for the feedback I am finding alot of mistakes :/ its a good book though

Comment: Probability and Statistics by asimow published by acetex

Comment: Is the title of your question taken from the book? The word *between* can cause confusion. Are $1$ and $100$ candidates to be chosen?...

Comment: If $1$ or $100$ is excluded, or even _both_, the probability goes _up_, not down. For instance, if $1$ is excluded, $\frac{85-68}{100-1} = \frac{17}{99} > 0.17$.

Comment: the wording says from 1-100 so I beileve that it includes 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substract $68$ to all numbers in you interval.You get the interval from 1 to 17. therefore there are the same quantity as the numbers between 1 and 17. Clearly there are 17 of these.

Assuming each number is equally likely there are 17 favourable cases out of 100 possible cases. So the odds are $\frac{17}{100}=0.17$